# how to use a page (joomla article) using joomla plugin in another website on page load?

Tags: java, jsp, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am using joomla for loading some static content for my web application. now i have the requirement that create a page in joomla that loads when application url gets hit on browser.
Basically the flow would be:
1) enter application url.
2) page will display a promotional video with page_mask effect.
3) the player will disappear on "ESC" and homapage will appear of web application.

I have done video embedding part(without ESC control) by using joomla plugin as it was the main requirement, but the problem is that i want to use this page in my web application with the same funcationality and it should be managed by joomla.

This issue is of high priority. I would be grateful if i get quick response related to the issue.

Thanks,
Vikram

Comment: Please give us specific information. ie. Show us the code you used and the name of the plugins etc. Otherwise it is hard to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAve tried this in the past with general success (had to modify for our own use)
[Simple Pop-Up](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/popups-a-iframes/17214)